# How to do a modal segue and pop to root in navigation controller simultaneously?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I would like to pop to the root behind the curtains, while presenting a new view controller modally. When the user is done with this new view controller, it will be dismissed and the root view controller of the navigationcontroller will be behind it.

I've tried using

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

Inside the `prepareForSegue:` method but it shows the root viewcontroller before the modal view controller is totally presenting (hence showing to the user what's happening behind the curtains, which is not a desirable feature to have).

If trying to pop in `viewDidLoad:` of the modally presented view controller, nothing happens at all.

What's the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turn things around and dismiss the modal plus `popToRootViewController` at the same time.

Not sure if you can do this with StoryBoards (since I'm more of an XIB guy), so you may need to bit more code.

Comment: This will cause a `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Pushed VC here>`, which hopefully is just a warning and does not cause any issues. But it works.

Comment: I did not use this answer, just adding what I know. I ended up manually manipulating the view controller array.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to achieve this.  This one will pop the FirstViewController off the stack in the background via delegation.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var presentModal: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "presentModal", sender: nil)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "presentModal" {
            let destVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let topVC = destVC.topViewController as! SecondViewController
            topVC.delegate = self
        }
    }


}

extension FirstViewController: SecondViewControllerDelegate {

    func didDismissModal(_ controller: SecondViewController) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    }

}

protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func didDismissModal(_ controller: SecondViewController)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
         self.delegate?.didDismissModal(self)
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```